# Getting an error while installing Hybris b2b in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to install Hybris b2b in my local machine which is using Ubuntu OS, I'm getting the following error.

> external process returned non-zero exit code, command: [sh, -c, export PLATFORM_HOME="/usr/sap/hybris/hybris/bin/platform" && export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m" && export ANT_HOME="/usr/sap/hybris/hybris/bin/platform/apache-ant-1.9.1" && chmod +x "/usr/sap/hybris/hybris/bin/platform/apache-ant-1.9.1/bin/ant" &&  export PATH="$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH" &&  ant extgen -Dhybris.target=extgen -Dinput.template=yacceleratorstorefront -Dinput.name=yb2bacceleratorstorefront -Dinput.package=de.hybris.platform.yb2bacceleratorstorefront]

Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give some more information? This error dont say much...

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly-related KBA on "SAP Hybris Commerce 6.0" which contains an "external process returned non-zero exit code" error message: https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002345016

However, it's for the sap_aom_som_b2b_b2c recipe.

Anyway, it says the issue has been fixed in 6.1.

In any case, have you tried downloading the latest patch for the version that you are using? Also, you haven't specified which version you are using. (e.g. 6.5.0.1)